# Kivy on Qpython3 (Android)

Tags: kivy, qpython, qpython3

How I can use the Kivy framework in Qpython3 (Python 3.2 for android) app?
I know that Qpython (Python 2.7 for android) app support this framework.
pip_console don't install kivy. I have an error, when I try to install it. Please help me.

Comment: Please add code example, error details, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: Kivy now supports python3 on Android, though qpython would still have to include this (or a similar build process) to have kivy work in qpython3.**

You can't right now, as kivy does not have a python3-supporting backend on android.

We're working towards adding one, at which point I quess qpython may look at adding support in qpython3.

Answer (score 0):

From kivy documentation http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html

> NOTE: Currently, packaging only works with Python 2.7. We are working on Python 3.3+ support, but for now if you plan to distribute your package on any platform you should use Python 2.7.

Comment: Hmm, this is out of date, packaging on desktop should work with python3

Comment: No need to apologise - it's a good researched answer and our fault that it's wrong! I've raised an issue about it (other people know more about packaging than me).